# ValueError when outputting to file with str.format

Tags: python

I would like to print `0.0` in a file 10 times. However, I get an invalid syntax error with the code below:

```
fl.write(('{:8.2f}\n'*10).format('0.0'*10))
```

How do I fix this? I do want to keep it as concise as possible and not have to write 0.0 10 times explicitly.

Comment: You are right, I get this error: unknown format code 'f' for object of type str. Seems like I cannot use '0.0'*10 in the format part?

Comment: That's because you are trying to format strings, not the expected floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `ValueError` because you are trying to format one string as a float number:

```
('{:8.2f}\n'*10).format('0.0'*10)
```

The `f` formatter expected a float value, not a string like `'0.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0'`, which is what you produced.

Instead of formatting just use a string literal, you have a fixed value:

```
fl.write('    0.00\n' * 10)
```

or at the very least produce 10 floating point numbers:

```
fl.write(('{:8.2f}\n'*10).format(*([0.0] * 10)))
```

Here `*([0.0] * 10)` produces a list object with ten references to the floating point value `0.0`, then applies that list as separate arguments to the `str.format()` method.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> fl = sys.stdout
>>> fl.write('    0.00\n' * 10)
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
90
>>> fl.write(('{:8.2f}\n'*10).format(*([0.0] * 10)))
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
    0.00
90
```

Comment: @user308827: no. `[0.0]` creates a list. `[0.0] * 10` extends that list to contain the value 10 times. `*listobject` applies all elements in the list as separate arguments.

Comment: perfect, ty. I will accept you answer in a few minutes, stackoverflow is asking me to wait 4 more min